# JT400 - get messages from Queue

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I would like to get messages in AS400 from a queue other than a queue from QSYS.LIB. I am using the following code that runs well, only if I use a queue from within QSYS.LIB:

```
public String getMessagesFromQsysopr(boolean needReply) {


    String messageStr = "";
    try {

    MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(this.as400, "/qsys.lib/qsysopr.msgq");
 // want only inquiry messages
    queue.setSelectMessagesNeedReply(needReply);
    queue.setSelectMessagesNoNeedReply(!needReply);
    queue.setSelectSendersCopyMessagesNeedReply(needReply);
    queue.setListDirection(false);

    Enumeration e = queue.getMessages();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        QueuedMessage message = (QueuedMessage) e.nextElement();
        messageStr += message.getText()+"\n";
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I replace the /qsys.lib/qsysopr.msgq for any other queue from other lib, like for example "/yaclib.lib/queueName.msgq" I get the following error:

com.ibm.as400.access.IllegalPathNameException: /yaclib.lib/queueName.msgq: **Object not in QSYS file system**.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.QSYSObjectPathName.parse(QSYSObjectPathName.java:599)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.QSYSObjectPathName.(QSYSObjectPathName.java:169)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.QSYSObjectPathName.(QSYSObjectPathName.java:177)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.MessageQueue.(MessageQueue.java:299)
    at br.com.operation.AS400Inspector.getMessagesFromYaclib(AS400Inspector.java:225)
    at br.com.operation.Main.main(Main.java:43)

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong?

**Question 2:** Is there any way to limit the messages that don't need reply? Like get messages after a specific date or just the last 2 day messages?

Thanks.

Comment: `...for example "/yaclib.lib/queueName.msgq"` That's not a valid name. There is no _file system_ named **/yaclib.lib**. You want to reference library YACLIB. Using the IFS naming format, you'd start the path with the /qsys.lib file system so it becomes "/qsys.lib/yaclib.lib/queueName.msgq".

Comment: There is a method to QSYS'ify a given library+member in one of the IFS classes.  Very handy to do this properly (there is a lot of rules to follow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user2338816 is correct.

`QSYS` is a special library; it actually contains every other library in the system.  From a 5250 session, WRKOBJ *ALL *LIB will confirm that every library is the system is in the QSYS library.  Interestingly, QSYS itself is contained in QSYS.

When using IFS naming, to refer to a library of `YACLIB.LIB`, you need to use `/QSYS.LIB/YACLIB.LIB`

As far as selecting by date, no there's no way to do that.  If you look at the [java docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/MessageQueue.html) the closest you'll find is `NEW, NEWEST, OLD, OLDEST`

Comment: IFS naming is a work around to allow accessing libraries through a Unix-like file tree in addition to /usr and /tmp etc..  For the purpose of this question consider it a mount point for the AS/400 libraries.